# How to make GET request with raw string as param

Tags: c#, json, get, servicestack

I have the next API URL to get friends of user on web site http://api.dev.socialtord.com/api/Friend/GetFriends. According to the docs
http://api.dev.socialtord.com/Help/Api/GET-api-Friend-GetFriends it requires raw json string with user id as param. All my attempts to get correct response are failed.

Service:

```
public class FriendsService
{
    readonly string _apiUrl = "http://api.dev.socialtord.com/api";

    public JsonServiceClient CallClient()
    {
        // wire up call
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(_apiUrl);
        return client;
    } 

    public List<FriendListModel> GetFriends(long userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = CallClient();
            var response = client.Get<GetFriendsResponse>(new GetFriends() { UserId = userId} );
            if (response.ErrorMessage == null)
                return response.Result;
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[GetFriends Excetion] " + e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
[Route("/Friend/GetFriends", "GET")]
public class GetFriends : IReturn<GetFriendsResponse>, IReturnVoid
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Response:

```
public class GetFriendsResponse
{
    public List<FriendListModel> Result { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; } 
}
```

Model:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class FriendListModel
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerHandle { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public long RelatedUserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }
    public long UserRelationshipId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should not use tags in question title.

Comment: readonly string _apiUrl = "http://api.dev.socialtord.com/api/Friend/GetFriends"

Comment: U did not specify full URL for the API Method you are calling

Comment: @Kofi Amparbeng, relative url appended with route in request